# UPDATE statement in BigQuery that sets _PARTITIONDATE equal particular date field in your table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update, data-partitioning

I have a table in BigQuery with a date column called `dt` where all data for all dates is currently in the partition `DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)="2022-01-20"`. I want to run an `UPDATE` statement that makes `dt=DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)` for all partitions. For example, where DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)="2022-01-19" there will only be data where dt="2022-01-19", where DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)="2022-01-18" there will only be data where dt="2022-01-18" and so on.

This is something that I have done in the past so I know is possible, I just can't remember exactly what the statement was.

Comment: Do you need the table to be partitioned by ingestion time? If not, you could use "dt" as the partition field instead of the "_PARTITIONTIME" pseudocolumn

Comment: Thanks for the response! I may not need it to be partitioned by ingestion time thinking about it. What would be the best way to partition it using the "dt" field?

Comment: I think I have found the statement actually, something like this seems to have worked:

`CREATE TABLE my_dataset.my_table
PARTITION BY DATE(dt)
AS (SELECT * FROM my_dataset.orig_table );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Creating a partitioned table

Since you don't need a table partition by ingestion time, you can create your table using your own date field as the partition field. You can do so by adding the "PARTITON BY" statement when creating a table, like this

```
CREATE TABLE `project_id.mydataset.mytable` (
  field1 STRING,
  dt TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY DATE(dt)
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `project_id.mydataset.mytable`
PARTITION BY DATE(dt)
AS (
  SELECT * FROM `project_id.mydataset.othertable`
)
```

## Updating the _PARTITIONTIME

Addressing your original question, if you need you can also update the _PARTITIONTIME field. To set all _PARTITIONTIME fields equal to your dt column, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE
  project_id.dataset.mytable
SET
  _PARTITIONTIME = dt
WHERE
  1=1
```

If dt has a different granularity than _PARTITIONTIME (_PARTITIONTIME granularity is day and dt is hour, for example), than you can do a TIMESTAMP_TRUNC

```
UPDATE
  project_id.dataset.mytable
SET
  _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP_TRUNCT(dt, DAY)
WHERE
  1=1
```